# Trying to use an image for submit buttons in multipart/form-data

Tags: html

I have a project where I am trying to convert an old style form to something more modern.  The form is a **multipart/form-data**, and has multiple entry fields and different submit options per table row.  Below are some screenshots and a copy of the code.  I hope it makes sense, as I have trimmed down the code to a single row to make is smaller.  Normally this form can grow to hundreds of rows.

I have searched everywhere, and I won't go into all the variants I have tried, but the closest I got to getting it to work was using the `<button>` tag, however, it would not post to the server.

Here is a jsfiddle of the code I am using: http://jsfiddle.net/kbbz19zm/

```
<form method="post" action="/CM/cmach" enctype="multipart/form-data" onreset="document" name="edittmpl">
<table class="accts" border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
             <h4>Participant</h4>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
             <h4>ABA</h4>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
             <h4>Account</h4>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
             <h4>Tran Type</h4>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
             <h4>Amount</h4>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
             <h4>ID Num</h4>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
             <h4>Disc Data</h4>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
             <h4>Addenda Info</h4>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
             <h4>Actions</h4>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tabledetail">
        <td align="center">
             <h6>Joe Schmoe</h6>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
             <h6>0101010101</h6>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
             <h6>CK  -  10001000111001</h6>
        </td>
        <td class="blankcell1" align="left">
             <h6><label><input type="radio" name="part_debit_credit_Damon Lewis:_:0101010101:_:CK:_:10001000111001" value="Withdrawal" />Withdrawal</label><br /> <label><input type="radio" name="part_debit_credit_Damon Lewis:_:0101010101:_:CK:_:10001000111001" value="Deposit" checked="checked" />Deposit</label><br /></h6>
        </td>
        <td class="blankcell1" align="center">
            <input name="part_amount_Damon Lewis:_:0101010101:_:CK:_:10001000111001" maxlength="14" type="text" value="0.00" size="8" override="1" />
        </td>
        <td class="blankcell1" align="center">
            <input name="part_id_num_Damon Lewis:_:0101010101:_:CK:_:10001000111001" maxlength="15" type="text" value="" size="8" override="1" />
        </td>
        <td class="blankcell1" align="center">
            <input name="part_disc_data_Damon Lewis:_:0101010101:_:CK:_:10001000111001" maxlength="2" type="text" value="" size="1" override="1" />
        </td>
        <td class="blankcell1" align="center">
            <input name="part_addenda_Damon Lewis:_:0101010101:_:CK:_:10001000111001" maxlength="80" type="text" value="" size="15" override="1" />
        </td>
        <td class="blankcell1" align="center">
            <input name="edit_tmpl_part_Damon Lewis:_:0101010101:_:CK:_:10001000111001" type="submit" value="Update" />
            <input name="del_tmpl_part_conf_Damon Lewis:_:0101010101:_:CK:_:10001000111001" type="submit" value="Delete" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input name="edit_switch" type="hidden" value="on" />
<input name="tmpl_val" type="hidden" value="Schmoe Enterprises" />
</form>
```

Here are screenshots of what works currently and what I am trying to achieve.
The current is using input type="submit":

edit: for some reason the forum doesn't like this link as an image, I'll try again.
http://s4.postimg.org/5a3hokc9p/Image3.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your replies.  I ended up abandoning using actual images for the icon buttons, and instead used a custom font similar to webdings or wingdings, with some CSS styling.

Below is the code and screenshots:

HTML:

```
<input name="mark_batch_conf_2015006:_:1" class="buttonIcons" title="Mark" type="submit" value="m" id="blue" />
<input name="edit_batch_2015006:_:1" class="buttonIcons" title="Edit" type="submit" value="a" id="orange" />
```

CSS

```
.buttonIcons { 
   font-family:"Icons", helvetica; 
   color:#636363; 
   font-weight:normal; 
   font-size:24px; 
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: baseline;
   border-radius: 15px;
   outline: none;
   border: none;
   cursor: pointer;
   background: transparent;
  }
#blue { color: #5e83cc; }
#blue:hover ,
#blue:active {
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.9);
   transition: color 0.2s ease-in;
   position: relative; 
   top: -1px;
   left: -1px;
   color: #539cd0;
}
```

The font I used: Sosa-Regular (http://tenbytwenty.com/?xxxx_posts=sosa)

Screenshot:
http://s30.postimg.org/v5w2qo1el/Untitled.png

Answer (score 0):

Use `type="image"` for the input if you want it to act like a submit button. You can set an image for it using the `src` attribute.

```
<td class="blankcell1" align="center">
    <input name="edit" type="image" src="http://placehold.it/20x20">
    <input name="delete" type="submit" value="Delete">
</td>
```

Demo:

```css
table{border:solid CornflowerBlue 1px;border-radius:8px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;max-width:1024px;-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 5px 0 rgba(128,128,128,0.9);-moz-box-shadow:0 3px 5px 0 rgba(128,128,128,0.9);box-shadow:0 3px 5px 0 rgba(128,128,128,0.9)}
h1{text-align:left;font-family:"Open Sans",helvetica;font-weight:bold;font-size:20px;color:#f9f3f3;margin:8px;border:0;text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(32,32,192,0.4),0px -1px 0 rgba(32,32,192,0.2)}
h2{font-family:"Open Sans",helvetica;font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;color:#f9f3f3;margin:8px;border:0;text-align:left;padding:2px 0 4px 10px;border-radius:8px;background:url(/images/tablebg.png) center repeat-x;background-size:auto 100%;background:linear-gradient(#5c90be,#0053a0);max-width:1016px;text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(32,32,192,0.4),0px -1px 0 rgba(32,32,192,0.2)}
h5{font-family:"Open Sans",helvetica;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;color:#50575d;margin:4px;border:0;text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(32,32,32,0.1),0px -1px 0 rgba(32,32,32,0.1)}
h5.messagetext{font-family:"Open Sans",helvetica;font-weight:normal;font-size:16px;color:#c9c3c3;margin:4px;border:0;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(32,32,32,0.1),0px -1px 0 rgba(32,32,32,0.1)}
h3{font-family:"Open Sans",helvetica;font-weight:bold;color:#333;font-size:12px;margin:0;padding:0 2px 2px 5px}
#tc297{width:297px}
#tc97{width:97px}
#tc25{width:25px}
table{background-color:#fff}
td{border:0}
h4{font-family:"Open Sans",helvetica;font-weight:bold;color:#333;font-size:12px;margin:6px}
tr.tabledetail{background-color:#f7f7f7;border-radius:8px}
tr.tabledetail1{background-color:#efefef;border-radius:8px}
h6{font-family:"Open Sans",helvetica;font-weight:normal;color:#333;font-size:12px;margin:0;padding:2px 5px 2px 5px}
td.pad3{padding:3px}
td.title{background-color:#fff;border-bottom:1px CornflowerBlue solid;border-radius:8px;-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 7px 0 rgba(192,192,192,1);-moz-box-shadow:0 0 7px 0 rgba(192,192,192,1);box-shadow:0 0 7px 0 rgba(192,192,192,1)}
td.pad_bottom_border{padding-bottom:8px;border-bottom:1px CornflowerBlue solid;border-radius:8px}
td.tablelabelleft{border-bottom:1px white solid;border-top:1px white solid;border-radius:8px}
td.tablelabellefttopright{border-left:1px white solid;border-top:1px white solid;border-right:1px white solid;border-radius:8px}
td.tablelabellefttop{border-left:1px white solid;border-top:1px white solid;border-radius:8px}
td.tablelabel{border-bottom:1px white solid;border-left:1px white solid;border-top:1px white solid;border-radius:8px}
td.tablebottom{border-top:1px white solid;padding:2px;border-radius:8px}
td.blankcellb{border-left:1px white solid;border-radius:8px}
td.blankcellb1{border-left:1px white solid;border-radius:8px}
tbody tr.tabledetail:hover{background:#dce2e6}
tbody tr.tabledetail1:hover{background:#dce2e6}
input{font-family:"Open Sans",helvetica;color:#333;font-weight:normal;font-size:12px}
textarea{font-family:"Open Sans",helvetica;color:#333;font-weight:normal;font-size:12px}
select{font-family:"Open Sans",helvetica;color:#333;font-weight:normal;font-size:12px}
@font-face{font-family:'Open Sans';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;src:local('Open Sans Light'),local('OpenSans-Light'),url('/css/open_sans_light.woff') format('woff')}
@font-face{font-family:'Open Sans';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:local('Open Sans'),local('OpenSans'),url('/css/open_sans.woff') format('woff')}
@font-face{font-family:'Open Sans';font-style:normal;font-weight:600;src:local('Open Sans Semibold'),local('OpenSans-Semibold'),url('/css/open_sans_semibold.woff') format('woff')}
@font-face{font-family:'Open Sans';font-style:normal;font-weight:700;src:local('Open Sans Bold'),local('OpenSans-Bold'),url('/css/open_sans_bold.woff') format('woff')}
@font-face{font-family:'Open Sans';font-style:italic;font-weight:400;src:local('Open Sans Italic'),local('OpenSans-Italic'),url('/css/open_sans_italic.woff') format('woff')}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="/CM/cmach" enctype="multipart/form-data" onreset="document" name="edittmpl">
    <table class="accts" border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                 <h4>Participant</h4>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                 <h4>ABA</h4>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                 <h4>Account</h4>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                 <h4>Tran Type</h4>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                 <h4>Amount</h4>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                 <h4>ID Num</h4>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                 <h4>Disc Data</h4>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                 <h4>Addenda Info</h4>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                 <h4>Actions</h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tabledetail">
            <td align="center">
                 <h6>Joe Schmoe</h6>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                 <h6>0101010101</h6>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                 <h6>CK  -  10001000111001</h6>
            </td>
            <td class="blankcell1" align="left">
                 <h6><label><input type="radio" name="part_debit_credit_Damon Lewis:_:0101010101:_:CK:_:10001000111001" value="Withdrawal" />Withdrawal</label><br /> <label><input type="radio" name="part_debit_credit_Damon Lewis:_:0101010101:_:CK:_:10001000111001" value="Deposit" checked="checked" />Deposit</label><br /></h6>
            </td>
            <td class="blankcell1" align="center">
                <input name="part_amount_Damon Lewis:_:0101010101:_:CK:_:10001000111001" maxlength="14" type="text" value="0.00" size="8" override="1" />
            </td>
            <td class="blankcell1" align="center">
                <input name="part_id_num_Damon Lewis:_:0101010101:_:CK:_:10001000111001" maxlength="15" type="text" value="" size="8" override="1" />
            </td>
            <td class="blankcell1" align="center">
                <input name="part_disc_data_Damon Lewis:_:0101010101:_:CK:_:10001000111001" maxlength="2" type="text" value="" size="1" override="1" />
            </td>
            <td class="blankcell1" align="center">
                <input name="part_addenda_Damon Lewis:_:0101010101:_:CK:_:10001000111001" maxlength="80" type="text" value="" size="15" override="1" />
            </td>
            <td class="blankcell1" align="center">
                <input name="edit_tmpl_part_Damon Lewis:_:0101010101:_:CK:_:10001000111001" type="image" src="http://placehold.it/30&text=U" />
                <input name="del_tmpl_part_conf_Damon Lewis:_:0101010101:_:CK:_:10001000111001" type="image" src="http://placehold.it/30&text=D" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input name="edit_switch" type="hidden" value="on" />
    <input name="tmpl_val" type="hidden" value="Schmoe Enterprises" />
</form>
```

Comment: While this does show the images, it only posts the first iteration in the form.  I have also tried adding input type=hidden for each input in the form list.

Comment: @Bill-G Please clarify what you mean by "only posting the first iteration".

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have clarified better in my original post.  The page I am generating with perl creates a long list, sometimes hundreds of rows, each the same as the screenshot I provided.  on each row there are input fields and at the end of each row there is an update and a delete button that perform a submit form.  When I try to use the method of input type="image" along with an input type="hidden", no matter which button I press, data from the first submit is sent to the server.